# Isomorphism classes of trees with maximum degree $3$ and $6$ vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

**List the isomorphism classes of trees with maximum degree $3$ and $6$ vertices**.

I start with the star $K_{1,3}$ and append vertices accordingly to achieve $6$ vertices keeping maximum degree $3$. I found exactly $3$ classes for the case, $G_1,G_2,G_3$, which are-

[image]

However, the book doesn't mention $G_3$ as a possible class and I am unable to see why. It is a connected acyclic graph with $6$ vertices and maximum degree $3$ and doesn't seem to be isomorphic to the other graphs since there are $2$ vertices with degree $2$.

**EDIT**
Attaching the provided question plus solution in case, something trivial was overlooked.

> [image]
> [image]

Note that my question is specific to the case $k=3$ and $n=6$.

Comment: This seems correct to me, what solution is the book providing?

Comment: @DavidScholz it says there are only 2 isomorphism classes $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: Could you provide the reference to the book?

Comment: @DavidScholz The answer was provided in the solution manual to Introduction to Graph Theory by D.B. West 2nd Edition, question 2.1.1.

Comment: I'll attach a snippet of the solution to the question if that helps. It could be a typing error or a misedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both graphs $G_1$ and $G_3$ are included in the definition of $Q$. The word "growing" a leaf might be the key factor here. With "growing" we do not mean to add a single leaf, but to add a single path to a neighbour of a leaf.

Consider the path on $5$ vertices $v_1-v_2-v_3-v_4-v_5$.

For $G_1$ add an edge $(v_2,v_6)$ (or $v_4,v_6$). We **append** a leaf from a neighbour of a leaf, namely from the leaf $v_1$ (or $v_5$) and the diameter is $4$. This is the same as **growing** a $P_1$.

For $G_3$ add an edge $(v_3,v_6)$. Here we **grow** a leaf from a neighbour of a leaf as well.

Notice that for $T_{i,j}$ the author explicitly says "appending" leaves to the endpoints of the edge.

This slightly adjusted picture might help (excuse my poor drawing).

[image]

If this is not the correct explaination, then your answer is still correct (for the reasons you have provided) and the author made a mistake. To be 100% sure, we can always consult sage by running the following code

```
from sage.graphs.trees import TreeIterator

for t in TreeIterator(6):
    if t.degree_sequence()[0] == 3:
        t.show()
```

yielding to

[image]

Comment: The difference you pointed out between growing and appending seems to be the most likely explanation. Regardless, this clears my doubt. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome!